# Custom local font not applying in safari or IOS device but works on Chrome/Firefox with Next.js 14

Tags: next.js, browser, fonts, safari, cross-browser

This is my first stackoverflow post. I have been trying to figure out a solution as to why the font doesn't apply to Safari or any browser that is in an IOS device, but it works perfectly for Chrome, Firefox and other browsers.

I have followed optimal process for adding fonts to a Next.js 14 app per the documentations, I have a feeling it has to do with Apple's webkit or perhaps Next.js way of rendering these files? Surely its one of those.

I have made sure the font is webfont compatible using WOFF, and even tried using @font-face instead of Next.js's next/font method. Additionally, I have used the same exact font in a past project and that was a simple static HTML/CSS project and works as expected. This is why I believe it might have to do with the way Next.js is rendering these files?

Anyone with more experience or had experience similar to this please let me know, it would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

The issue definitely lies with how Next.js renders font loading and optimisation, at least it affects Safari. I have tested and override the font in CSS rather than using the recommended next/local/font method provided in Next.js docs.

It worked as expected, if anyone wants to chime in on this, let the world know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've met a similar issue: localFont doesn't render custom fonts in canvas in Safari. Haven't found solution yet

Comment: Any updates on your end? I am waiting for updates to Next.js, apparently it has to do with how next handles bundling and browsers (like safari) can't comprehend it.